# Sotre data inside image then retrieve data after print - scan

Tags: image-processing, pattern-matching, watermark, image-recognition

I have formal ms word files, a watermark (organization logo for example) should modified to store some meta-data related to the word file itself (the author, no of pages, ...), then this modified watermark should be inserted in the ms word file before printing.
In opposite way : after printing a watermarked ms word file -> we have to scan it and recognize the watermark and retrieve the stored meta data from inside it.
Any Help please,